# Intuition for vector calculus

Tags: statistics, vectors, intuition, matrix-calculus, fisher-information

In my statistics class, I was introduced to Fisher Information. As it comes from the Taylor Expansion in vector form, I wanted to know terms were ordered in a certain way - whether it was just to make it work or there was some intuition behind it. Taking the general Taylor Expansion as an example,

$f(x)=f(x_0)+\nabla f(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{1}{2}(x-x_0)^T\nabla\nabla^Tf(x_0)(x-x_0).$

I am mainly fussed with the quadratic term. Would I be correct in saying that $y^Ty$ is like squaring a number? And if so, what is the meaning and reasoning behind sticking the derivative between these two terms - why cannot it be interchanged with the first transpose.

Comment: When $\mathbf{y}$ is a vector, $\mathbf{y}^\top\mathbf{y}=|\mathbf y|^2$ is its magnitude squared, i.e. a scalar. Meanwhile, $\nabla\nabla^\top$ is an outer product, and gives you an operator which eats a vector-valued function and gives you another vector-valued function.

Comment: Thanks @DanDan0101 I like this idea. So considering the quadratic term, what would be the intuitive meaning of $\nabla\nabla^Tf(x_0)(x-x_0)$ or $(x-x_0)^T\nabla\nabla^Tf(x_0)$ if you choose to multiply that way first?

Comment: @Jackanap3s with a matrix $A$ and a vector $x$ we have $|A^Tx|^2=\langle A^Tx,A^Tx \rangle = (A^Tx)^TAx=x^TAA^Tx$ and you can see it's phrases similarly in this notation with a linear operation instead of a matrix.

Comment: @CyclotomicField What is our $A$ and $x$ in this case? I am assuming $x = x-x_0$. I am not sure about $A$?

Comment: @Jackanap3s $A$ works likes the gradient $\nabla$ which is a linear operator. We often replace a matrix with the linear operator it represents to avoid the complications that come with choosing a basis. Here, the gradient is a linear operator naturally and a matrix representation doesn't make as much sense but it's analogous.

Comment: You can read about the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix), which is the $\nabla\nabla^\top$ operator.

Comment: There is a mistake in the equation you wrote down; $f(x_0)$ is a scalar so it does not make sense to write $f(x_0)^T$. For the first order term we take the transpose of the operator $\nabla^T$; then $\nabla^T f$ is a transpose vector which acts on $x-x_0$ to generate a scalar. For the second order term the operator is $\nabla \nabla^T$ which generates a matrix; we then have a quadratic form $(x-x_0)^T (\nabla \nabla^Tf)  (x-x_0)$ which also generates a scalar. For the third order term the operator is a third order covariant tensor $\nabla \otimes \nabla \otimes \nabla$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thanks that makes sense, except why do we take $A^Tx$ instead of $Ax$?

Comment: @TedBlack What would the correct equation be?

Comment: Second term is $\nabla^T f(x_0) (x-x_0)$; $f$ is a scalar function so it does not have a transpose

Comment: @Jackanap3s I just used $A^Tx$ so that it would match the equation you were given. You can always set $B=A^T$ to see that the choice is arbitrary.

Comment: @TedBlack if $$f$$ is a scalar function, then is $$\nabla f(x_0)$$ scalar as I thought it would be a vector of partial derivates and similarly $$\nabla\nabla^Tf(x_))$$ would be a matrix of all possible 2nd order partial derivates.

Comment: $\nabla$ is a vector ; $f$ is a scalar ; $(x-x_0)$ is a vector. In the Taylor expansion of a scalar function we want all terms to be scalars ; so we have $\nabla^T f (x_0)(x-x_0)$ which is a scalar

Comment: @DanDan0101 If $$\nabla$$ and $$\nabla\nabla^T$$ are operators then do they both act on $$(x-x_0)$$ and then are scaled by $$f(x_0)$$? (Of course with the quadratic term you have a few more terms.)